# How to create package extension with dependencies package?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, package

I have created `Package1_Module1` extension.Now I Want to create another extension `Package1_Module2` so it is dependent on `Package1_Module1` so it is add-on `Package1_Module1`.
 what I have to write in `package` textbox and other stuff in **dependencies tab** ?

Comment: Hi, is your extesnion is live as i facing issues while testing the extesnion on my local machine before submitting

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217669/how-to-use-create-extension-package-in-magento-1-9?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that approach it's possible for Magento2 (by composer) not for Magento 1.x generally I see that the extensions with dependencies are packed together.

I mean, `Package_Module2` have `Module2` and `Module1` inside.

If `Module1` it's independent maybe you'll want to keep `Package_Module1` to be installed standalone.

Comment: Can I leave dependencies tab for package_module1 ?